# Windows Vista/7 dropping Mac Server share points

Tags: windows-7, windows-vista, mac-osx-server, network-share, server-message-block

My Windows Vista and Windows 7 clients are having problems maintaining access to SMB shares on a Mac server. The initial connection to the server appears to be OK, as the Windows clients can see all of the server share points. However, the client randomly drops a couple of the server share points although the clients can still see the server.

For example. If I have the following share points on the Mac server:

```
Share A
Share B
Share C
Share D
Share E
```

The Windows client can see these shares most of the time and can access them most of the time. But randomly a couple of the shares will just get dropped or go missing from the Windows client's ability to view them so I end up with something like:

```
Share B
Share D
Share E
```

All the share points are established int the same way with the same permission settings. My Mac OSX Server is set up with the following for SMB:

```
SMB sharing enabled
Standalone Server
Workgroup of `CORPORATE`
Allow Guest Access = YES
Client connections limit = 100
Authentication: NTLMv2 & Kerberos and NTLM
Code Page is Latin US (437)
This is a workgroup master browser
WINS registration is set to Enable WINS server (tried with setting off)
Enable virtual share points for homes YES
```

I noticed in my SMB file service log that the clients appear to connect OK, but I get the following error which implies a reset by either the server or the client:

```
/SourceCache/samba/samba-187.9/samba/source/lib/util_sock.c:read_data(534)
   read_data: read failure for 4 bytes to client 192.168.0.99. 
   = Connection reset by peer
```

I am a bit stumped as to a direction to turn to try and get this to resolve. Continued attempts to access the server from the client will reconnect to the share points, but they inevitably get dropped again in the near future.

Any and all help much appreciated.

Comment: Any wireless connections here, or is it all Ethernet? I've seen this behaviour with wireless connections and I cannot fix it.

Comment: All wired - no wireless. All on the same subnet with gigabit Ethernet.

Answer (score 0):

Is the server running OS X 10.5.x?  I have noticed sometimes I have to restart my Windows 7 machine, because the OS X 10.5.8 shared volumes don't all show up, or show up with a different name.

For Windows 7 Home Premium User 64-bit connecting to my OS X 10.5.8 server I have seen the:

"read failure for 4 bytes to client"

Error. The Windows client was using an Adobe CS3 app and it stopped responding, and I saw the "read failure for 4 bytes to client" error in the OS X 10.5.8 smb error log.

Comment: it is a 10.5.x. I'll try an upgrade to Snow Leopard server (ugh the cost...) and see if that fixes the problem.